# mysql query doesn't show anything not even an error

Tags: mysql

When I run this query in phpmyadmin:

```
SELECT * FROM events e LEFT JOIN venues v ON e.vid = v.vid
```

nothing happens. there is no error or anything at all, the same screen is simply returned to me.

but when I run this:

```
SELECT * FROM events LEFT JOIN venues ON events.vid = venues.vid
```

it works just fine. am i missing something?

table structures: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/28104350/help.png

Comment: wierd. both queries should run fine. :D

Comment: Looks fine to me, maybe try events AS e and venues AS v, although AS is optional, I would be curious to see if it makes any difference.

Comment: [I don't think there is anything wrong](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a9048/3)

Comment: it works with AS, but why? never happened before

Comment: How about backticks around the table names and alias's incase there is any conflict with those particular table or alias names and inbuilt functions or stored procs

Comment: You are right, backticks work as well.

Comment: @WilHan Try running the query directly from mysql cmd line or from a php query (rather then phpmyadmin) to see if it is a problem with the phpmyadmin sql parser rather then the query itself. I am running phpmyadmin 3.5.1 and can't replicate the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:
put `"AS"`

```
SELECT * FROM events AS e LEFT JOIN venues AS v ON e.vid = v.vid
```

Comment: `AS` is completely optional :D

Comment: Ah, it works with AS. but why do i need it here? I've never needed it before

Comment: we use AS in aliasing tables.. John Woo why you down vote my answer :(

Comment: newbie do you know why AS is needed here? other queries without AS still work, just not this one.

Comment: We use as to alias table name to avoid conflicts from other tables. and to make easy to code.

Answer (score -1):

you should use ***alias*** like below,

```
SELECT * FROM events as  e LEFT JOIN venues as  v ON e.vid = v.vid
```